# Is there a way to write 2 data items into the one input box in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I need to write 2 email address into one input field in blue prism. Using the write stage I can write one email address in, however after I write the second one in, it overwrites the first one. Is there a way to space them out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As you've come to figure out, a Write stage will generally replace the contents of the form control it is interacting with.

To counter this when writing, first read the current contents using a Read stage. Subsequently, use a Write stage to write the concatenation of the previous value as well as the content you want to append.

Your Write stage expression would look something like `[Current Field Value] & [Email Address to Add]`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways to achieve this :

1. Write Stage :
   Use a calculation stage before and appened both the valies.
   Then use a write stage to textbox.
2. Send keys & event
   Use send keys to write one text.
   click on textbox again and pass "End key" and write second value.